# Windows Update(KB4532693) fails to install on my Windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am running a Windows 10 home edition, I tried to install the following Update:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1FMS.png)

It reports back an error code, 0x800f081f.

I googled searched for a solution, tried all of them including enabling the .NET framework, Standalone Installer, manually downloading the update, none of them worked. I had the same issue with the 2020-01 Cumulative update. Any solutions?

Comment: Scroll down to "How to Fix Error Code 0x800F081F: A Summary">>>>>>>https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-error-code-0x800f081f-windows-10/

Comment: @Moab I have tried that too, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try the steps in the Windows Update Troubleshooter. There are a number of steps so work through all the steps. This approach often works for us.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: @John No, it doesn't work, I've just tried it. I found that many people on Reddit have the same issue.

Comment: This update installs properly on our machines, so at this point, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.  Use the second link, run in place and use the later option to Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John Yes, I've tried the "Reset this PC and keep all my files" in my recovery partition but it still fails, Do you have the pro or home version of Windows, I've read in a German Microsoft support, the issue persists in the home version.

Comment: You may need to back up and do a fresh install at this point

Comment: @John I tried the link you provided and it worked! You can add your answer. Thank you so much! Just curious why didn't "Reset this PC work" but the link you provided worked?

Comment: @John A quick google search, The reason why "Reset This PC" didn't work was that "Reset this PC" uses existing Windows files you reconstruct a Windows image, but the Microsoft tool downloads a fresh copy!

Comment: I did post an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For particularly troublesome update issues, do a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the second link in the Microsoft article below, select run in place and use the later option to Keep Everything. This will repair Windows and permit updates to work again.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10